# I need to reduce with average

Tags: ruby, average, reduce

```
a = [[24, 18.0], [24, 16.0], [25, 15.0]]
```

I need b = [[24, 17.0], [25, 15.0]]

The are 2 rules I need calculate average value of second item in sub-array i.e. `[24, 18.0], [24, 16.0] #=> [24, 17.0]` - this I can do separately myself, but I can't understand how to combine reduce with average like "ruby way" solutions in `a.collect{...}`

Comment: It's important that you show your work when asking a question. What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Ok, next time I post my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by` to group common keys, and `sum/size` to get the average:

```
b = a.group_by(&:first).map do |k,v| 
  [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+) / v.size]
end
```